# How come this represents the height of a trapezoid?

Tags: geometry

Why does this formula
$$h= \frac{\sqrt{(-a+b+c+d)(a-b+c+d)(a-b+c-d)(a-b-c+d)}}{2|b-a|}$$
represent the height of a trapezoid?

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoid

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a trapezoid with bases $a$ and $c$, so that the other two sides are $b$ and $d$. Divide your trapezoid into two right triangles (each of which has a side being $h$) and a rectangle by dropping perpendiculars from $a$ to $c$ in appropriate places. Now place the triangles side by side so they share the side $h$. The base of this triangle is $a-c$ and its other two sides are $b$ and $d$. Now write down the area of this triangle in two different ways. First $A=\frac{1}{2}(a-c)h$, and second using Heron's formula. This gives the desired relationship between $a,b,c,d$ and $h$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's getting clearer, but how come you write the area as 1/2 * b*h? Shouldn't it be 1/2 * (a-c)*h?

Comment: My mistake. I meant $b$ for the base (which is $a-c$), not the side $b$. I edited my post to fix it.

Comment: Okay, great. Now for the names of angles..

I have the triangle with sides d, b and base (a-c).

Will I be calling my angles: (A-C), D and B when I enter Heron's formula?

Comment: Heron's Formula gives the area of a triangle in terms of the side lengths, not the angles. The $s$ appearing in Heron's formula is the semi-perimeter of the triangle (one half the perimeter).

Comment: Thank you. I'm almost there.

Comment: Figured it all out! Thanks!